# SQL is 8 hours behind timezone set by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that is setting the timezone for the MySQL session. I have checked the output and it is sending the offset correctly, `+1:00` (Europe/London in DST). However, when I read the timestamp that has been placed in the database, it is eight hours behind. Why is this happening?

The MySQL server is setting the timestamp as the default value.

Comment: The "default value" is the value of the server. What is the timezone set as on the server? (Use `date` on the command line, it should show the timezone)

Comment: @aynber I cannot access the command line as this is a shared server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your database parameters:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/London';
// OR: SET time_zone = 'Europe/London';
// OR: SET @@session.time_zone = 'Europe/London';
```

Update timezone directly in the request:

```
SELECT ..., CONVERT_TZ(field, 'GMT', 'Europe/London') FROM ...
```

Define in the entry file (like `index.php`) the proper timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Additionally it can be done on server (sample, Ubuntu):

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/London
# do not forget to restart all services: nginx|Apache, mysql, ...
```

Comment: As I am on a shared server, I do not have the right privileges to use `GLOBAL`. However, I am already running the first command without `GLOBAL` - but I am passing the value `+1:00`.

Comment: @StellarDoor5319 In that case you could change parameter directly for your account (remove `GLOBAL`). Also all values from the database can be converted on fly: `CONVERT_TZ(field, 'GMT', 'Europe/London')`

Comment: Where do I need to put `CONVERT_TZ` in the query? By "field", do you mean that I must replace it with the name of the column to convert?

Comment: @StellarDoor5319 Yep, directly... but it's not needed if timezone variables have been changed; but can be used if you're not able / allowed to change them. In addition, it'll slightly downgrade the performance

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Reference [timezone mentioned on their website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) , shows you how to set it.

For the lazy ones

mysql > SET time_zone = timezone;

Comment: My PHP script is already running this command as part of a `multi_query()` statement. The MySQL insertion runs directly after it.